# How to fix Laravel-mix error on initial 'npm run dev': "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ="?

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, laravel-mix

My initial `npm run dev` (or `watch` or `production`) after a clean install of Laravel is being prematurely interrupted by a *SyntaxError: Unexpected token =* error message:

> ```
> $ npm run dev
>
> #@ watch /home/{...}/www-teste
>
>    mix watch
>
> [webpack-cli]
> /home/{...}/www-teste/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Mix.js:18
>     static _primary = null;
>                     ^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
>     at new Script (vm.js:83:7)
>     at NativeCompileCache._moduleCompile (/home/{...}/www-teste/node_modules/v8-compile-       
> cache/v8-compile-cache.js:240:18)
>     at Module._compile (/home/{...}/www-teste/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-   
> cache.js:184:36)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
>     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
>     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
>     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
>     at require (/home/{...}/www-teste/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
>     at module.exports (/home/{...}/www-teste/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js:2:17)
> ```

Steps To Reproduce:

1. laravel new www-teste (with or without *--dev*)
2. cd www-teste
3. npm install
4. npm run {dev|watch|production}

Software versions:

- Laravel Mix Version: 6.0.10 (npm list --depth=0)
- Node Version (node -v): 6.0.10
- NPM Version (npm -v): 6.0.10
- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

How can I install a clean version of Laravel and enable Laravel-mix?

Comment: I would definitely imagine this is down to your node version. Node 6 hit EOL April 2019 https://github.com/nodejs/Release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had problems lately with Laravel-mix in Ubuntu and I solved it by updating the NodeJS version.

Here are the commands to update NodeJS to the latest version 13.x in Ubuntu:

- curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_13.x | sudo -E bash -
- sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
- npm install & npm run dev